# Duda con Normalizr

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, redux

**Hola comunidad como estan?**

Estoy teniendo un problema al momento de normalizar una informacion que me llega desde mongodb.
Estoy usando Normalizr para ello.

La estructura de datos que me llega desde mi base de datos es la siguiente

```
    const datadb = await chats.leer() ---> Esta funcion trae los datos desde mongo
```

```
        autor: {
                id: data.autor.id,
                nombre: data.autor.nombre,
                apellido: data.autor.apellido,
                edad: data.autor.edad,
                alias: data.autor.alias,
                avatar: data.autor.avatar
            },
        texto: {
                texto: data.texto
            },
        date: new Date().toLocaleDateString()
```

he creado 3 schemas, uno para autor, otro para texto y uno que engloba ambos.

```
        const autorSchema = new schema.Entity("autor");
        const textoSchema = new schema.Entity('texto', {}, { idAttribute: 'texto' })
        const mensaje = new schema.Entity("mensaje", {
           autor: autorSchema,
           texto: textoSchema
});
```

cuando ejecuto la funcion normalizr

const normalizedData = normalize(datadb, [mensaje]);

estoy obteniendo el siguiente resultado:

```
{
  entities: {
    autor: {
      'a@b.com': {    
        id: 'a@b.com',
        nombre: 'a',
        apellido: 'b',
        edad: '31',
        alias: 'ab',
        avatar: ''
      }
    },
    texto: { prueba1: { texto: 'prueba1' } },
    mensaje: {
      undefined: {
        _id: 6146009eafb0c4590ca35da3,
        autor: 'a@b.com',
        texto: 'prueba1',
        date: '18/9/2021'
      }
    }
  },
  result: [ undefined ]
}
```

mi duda es, porque el result y el mensaje poseen "undefined"? Deberia de poseer un Id key, pero no se como definirlo.

Agradezco la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Se que es super vieja la pregunta, pero para que no quede sin respuesta:

Sin un campo id no hay schema, y tomando en cuenta que cada mensaje va a tener 1 texto, no haria falta hacer un textoSchema.

Saludos.